# looking for iOS volume button animation

Tags: ios, animation, core-animation

[image]

Any custom ios control that does something like the volume button, with the ticker sound. I want to use this as a menu picker in my project, once saw a control like this but forgot. Any help is much appreciated.

Or if any one has seen the number lock animation in iOS, that would also be good. Something like the below image. I am going to use this for a menu sort of a thing. [image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this by using Round progress bar. below shown links will help you do this :

https://github.com/magicalpanda/MGPRoundProgressButton

http://code4app.net/ios/Round-Progress-Button/4f86dad606f6e76614000000

http://www.codertakeout.com/v/351662/592D4

Comment: `MGPRoundProgressButton` is promising, but some users reported in the Internet that positioning is incorrect in iOS 6.

Comment: I haven't seen such kind of issue yet. Am also working on it right now and will provide you good solution soon.

Comment: [this sample code](https://github.com/Ceroce/CERoundProgressView) will  definitely help you.

Comment: Thanks guys, but this is not what i want. The user should be able to rotate the view and according to it a action should happen.

Comment: I've just provided you an idea. Using those code examples is completely upto you. you have to use it just like we use a normal progress bar,whose value changes according to user interaction.Here,just change the value on touch.

Answer (score 1):

Check out NDRotator on Cocoa Controls. It looks like it's a rotating knob control that does what you want. It should be a simple matter to adapt it to use an image as the knob instead of the drawn graphic it currently uses.

You'd probably have to add the tick sound yourself however.